Give examples of open and closed sets
Task: Let the topology $T = \{\emptyset; \mathbb{R}; \left(-\infty, 1/2^{n}\right], n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be given on the line $X=\mathbb{R}.$
Give examples of:
a) an open but not closed set
b) a closed but not open set
c) neither an open nor a closed set.
Please, tell me if I understand correctly that for point a) the set $\left(-\infty, 1/2\right]$ is correct, because its complement $\left(1/2, +\infty \right)$ doesn't belong to the topology, and for point b) for example $\left[1/2, +\infty \right)$ is correct because its complement $\left(-\infty, 1/2\right)$ belongs to the topology and for point c) for example, $\left(0,1\right)$ is correct?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't quite understand if my answer is appropriate in a) because 1/2 is the limit point, will the set then be open? after all, it must contain all its internal points. I just started learning topology and I don't really understand how it works.

It seems correct to me. Just a little correction: in part b) the example should be $(1/2,+\infty)$ because its complementary is indeed $(-\infty,1/2]$ which belongs to the topology.
